# Is there an R equivalent of the pythonic "if __name__ == "__main__":     main()"?

Tags: python, r

The objective is to have two simple ways to source some code, say func.R, containing a function. Calling `R CMD BATCH func.R` initializes the function and evaluates is. Within a session, issuing `source("func.R")` simply initializes the function.
Any idea?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? The title question is different from the ideas in the actual body of the question

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I think that the `interactive()` function might work.

This function returns `TRUE` when R is being used interactively and `FALSE` otherwise. So just use `if (interactive())`

i.e. the equivalent is

```
if (!interactive()) {
  main()
}
```

Comment: Excellent, I had no idea this existed. I think this will change the way I write R.

Comment: With the Rscript shebang line and this our R scripts will be more pythonic than ever before!

Comment: @gappy Can you update this answer? I feel like this answer doesn't answer your question in the title. It mainly tells you whether the R file is being sourced on commandline or using Rscript.

Comment: This doesn't work if you're calling the main script with `rscript` and other files are `source`d.

Comment: `Interactive()` does not behave exactly like `__name__ == '__main__'`. Sourcing file `a.R` from `b.R` where file `a.R` has `print(interactive())` will return `True`. As @JAD mentioned.

Answer (score 47):

Another option is:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

# runs only when script is run by itself
if (sys.nframe() == 0){
# ... do main stuff
}
```

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer as it allows for a script to be sourced and the snippet within the if block not executed.

Comment: would you know why on my end if I position sys.nframe()  where you did it shows value equal to 4 and not 0 ?

Comment: Works like intended. But this doesn't include any automatization in RStudio (e.g. clicking "Source") which calls the script internally.

Answer (score 5):

You could pass arguments into R, and if an argument is present run main(). More on arguments here: http://yangfeng.wordpress.com/2009/09/03/including-arguments-in-r-cmd-batch-mode/

Comment: I voted the other answer, but I didn't know you could pass arguments from the command line either. That's helpful.

Comment: Since about the beginning of 2009 it's been possible to run R scripts with a shebang line, e.g. `#!/usr/bin/Rscript --vanilla` directly from the command line: e.g. run `chmod 700 my_script.r` to make it executable, and then you can run the script with `./my_script.r` (within the script you read arguments the same way as in the link above, by `args=(commandArgs(TRUE))`

Answer (score 3):

It's a lot of work, but I finally got it (and posted at [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/ScriptedMain#R)).

This example exports a function called `meaningOfLife`. When the script is run by itself, it runs `main`. When imported by another R file, it does not run `main`.

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

meaningOfLife <- function() {
    42
}

main <- function(program, args) {
    cat("Main: The meaning of life is", meaningOfLife(), "\n")
}

getProgram <- function(args) {
    sub("--file=", "", args[grep("--file=", args)])
}

args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = FALSE)
program <- getProgram(args)

if (length(program) > 0 && length(grep("scriptedmain", program)) > 0) {
    main(program, args)
    q("no")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I asked a similar question, [in an answer, Matthew Plourde suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21383886/2641825) using `getOption('run.main', default=TRUE)` in the main script and then setting `options(run.main=FALSE)` before calling `source()`. This worked in my case.

Otherwise a simpler pattern when you have an R script creating a bunch of functions and you want to write a few lines at the end of the script to experiment with the use of a function: place these extra lines in an `if(FALSE){}` block.

Answer (score 1):

This works fairly well for my use.  If you have two files and want to source one with the other while only running a certain part of the file.

parent file: parent.R

```
print("Running Parent File")
`__name__` <- "__main__"
print(paste0("This file is : ", `__name__`))

`__src__` <- "__not.main__"
source("child.R")
rm(`__src__`)
```

child file: child.R

```
print("Running Child File")
`__name__` <- "__main__"
if (exists("__src__")){`__name__` <- `__src__`}

if (`__name__` == "__main__"){
  print(paste0("This file is : ", `__name__`))
} else {
  print(paste0("This file is : ", `__name__`))
}
```

Output when running Rscript parent.R

```
[1] "Running Parent File"
[1] "This file is : __main__"
[1] "Running Child File"
[1] "This file is : __not.main__"
```

Output when running Rscript child.R

```
[1] "Running Child File"
[1] "This file is : __main__"
```

A more robust method would be to write a custom source function where a list of arguments can be included.

```
source2 <- function(file, args = list()){
    
  tryCatch(
    expr = {
      assign("__src__", "__not.main__", envir = globalenv())
      assign("__src.args__", args, envir = globalenv())
      source(file)
    },
    error = function(e){
      message("File could not be sourced")
    },
    finally = {
      rm(list = c("__src__", "__src.args__"), envir = globalenv());
      assign("__name__", "__main__", envir = globalenv())
    })
}

source2("child.R", args = list("list", "of", "arguments"))
```