# Scripted main behaviour in R?

Tags: r, knitr, scriptedmain

Working with `knitr`  has introduced a new problem -- many of my `R` scripts include picture generating code, and the plotting code slows things down when i source the code.

My idea is to move plotting code into a group that only runs if the code is being executed at the upper level, and not run when the code is sourced by another R-script, via the `source()` idiom.  Is this possible?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968220/is-there-an-r-equivalent-of-the-pythonic-if-name-main-main) old SO question, however `interactive()` will always be `TRUE` in my case, so the accepted answer does not work.

My case is as follows: I have a file, `myKnit.rnw`, and run it by sending it from `vim` to `R`, using the `vim-r-plugin`.  Thus, `interactive()` is always going to be `TRUE`, and `length(sys.frames())` will be non-zero -- as the `vim-r-plugin` basically works via applying `base::source(...)` to a temporary file.

The solution i am looking for is an `R` equivalent to the `python` idiom `if __name__ == __main__`.

Thus when `myKnit.rnw` runs and sources `myscript.r` via `source("~/R/myscript.r")`, the `if` evaluates to `FALSE` and the plotting code in `myscript.r` does not run.

In python terms, `__name__` (or whatever we call it) would not be `__main__` when `myKnit.rnw` sources `myscript.r`, but would be true when i send `myscript.r` to the console from `vim`.

example `knitr` code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\title{A Minimal Example}
\author{ricardo}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}[fragile]
source the code and then use the plot

<<source_plotScript, include=FALSE>>=
source("~/rwd/plotScript.r")
@
a histogram!
<<histy, fig.width=7, fig.height=5, messages=FALSE, warnings=FALSE>>=
print(pp)
@
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and here's the plot script that's sourced:

```
require(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(100)
pp <- qplot(x, geom = 'histogram')

pdf("seed1Hist.pdf")
print(pp)
dev.off()
```

Solution with system specific flags, reflecting Yihui's comment

```
fromSource <- function()
{
    knitSysSwitch <- function()
    { 
        switch(Sys.info()[['sysname']], 
               Windows = 'source', 
               Darwin = 'base::source')
    }
    length(sys.frame()) >= 4 && sys.call(1)[[1]] == knitSysSwitch()
}
```

Comment: Can you show us a minimum example of your .rnw file that produces this? It will simplify things to have everyone work from the same example.

Comment: @Thomas, i beg your pardon -- i just made a simple example at home on my mac, and had no problems ... suggests that it's either a windows thing, or there's some other problem with the code. I'll check at work and confirm -- else i'll delete this question.

Comment: @Thomas, I looked at things carefully on my mac at home, and though the error does not occur, the issue remains that lots of plotting code slows things down a lot (especially using `ggplot2`) so the work-around is still very desirable. Made a small edit to reflect changed catalyst & added example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
if (length(sys.frames()) >= 4 && sys.call(1)[[1]] == quote(base::source)) {
  # plot them
}
```

When the code is evaluated via `source()`, there are at least four frames in the stack. `sys.call()[[1]]` extracts the function symbol in the call, which I think is similar to `__name__` in Python.

BTW, perhaps you are aware of this: when you are working in `knitr`, you can turn on the cache using the chunk option `cache=TRUE` to speed up the time-consuming plotting code.

Comment: +1, accepted.  I work between `mac` and `windows`, and the `source` behaviour of the `vim-r-plugin` varies, so i added the following helper `knitSysSwitch <- function(){ switch(Sys.info()[['sysname']],      Windows = 'source', Darwin = 'base::source')}`, and edited the test to be `if (length(sys.frames()) >= 4 && sys.call(1)[[1]] == knitSysSwitch())`.

Comment: @ricardo or wrap everything into one function, e.g. `if (from_source()) {plot...}`, and `from_source = function() {...Sys.info()...sys.call()...whatever...}`