# Is if(interactive()) an R equivalent to the pythonic “if __name__ == ”__main__“: main()”?

Tags: python, r

I would like R scripts to have a main() function that gets executed while in interactive mode. But the main() function should not be executed while sourcing the file.

[There is already a question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968220/is-there-an-r-equivalent-of-the-pythonic-if-name-main-main) and a very good answer suggests using the interactive() function. However this doesn't work for me. I don't have enough reputation points to comment or answer in that question. So I ask the question here again.

I write this in `script_1.r`

```
if(interactive()){
  your main code here
}
```

- If I use knitr to waive a html or pdf document, sourcing the script. This code under `if(interactive())` won't be executed. This is good for me, that's what I want.
- My problem is that if I `source("script_1.r")` from `script_2.r` in interactive mode, it will still run the code under this `if(interactive())` part.

  - Is there a way to prevent the `if(interactive())` part to run when sourcing it from another script?
- I would like the `if(interactive())` code to run only when calling that script directly.

Comment: To be clear, you want the interactive bit to execute when you use knitr, but not when you source the script directly?

Comment: No I don't want the if(interactive()) bit to execute at all. Neither when running knitr, nor when sourcing from an other script.

Comment: I actually found an easier, way, I put my code in a if(FALSE){ } section, then it doesn't get executed at all. Most of the time this is what I want.

Comment: Yet another reason why python is awesome and R most definitely isn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to get the kind of control you're looking for is to use options.

For instance, 'script.r' would look like this:

```
main <- function() {
    message('main!')
}

if (getOption('run.main', default=TRUE)) {
   main()
}
```

If you are sourcing the file in interactive mode and don't want `main` to execute, simply call `options(run.main=FALSE)` before you call `source`. If you are using the script with knitr and you want `main` to execute, don't set the option, and it will default to `TRUE`. Or if you don't want the main to run with knitr, call `options(run.main=FALSE)` before calling it.

Comment: Thank you Matthew, I didn't know you could set options that way. It does what I want.

Comment: I set the option to FALSE before sourcing the script and set it back to TRUE afterwards.
options(run.load.main=FALSE)
source("code/load.r")
options(run.load.main=TRUE)

Answer (score 1):

As you’ve noticed, no, it’s not the same thing. `if(interactive())` does exactly what the name says – it tests whether the code is run in an interactive shell. No more, no less.

There’s no direct equivalent of `if __name__ == '__main__'` from Python in R, since R has no concept of modules in the same way as Python, and `source`’d code is just executed directly.

You could write your own `source` command to replace the default one and perform the necessary check, however.

That said, the question you’ve linked *does* [contain an answer which presents a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7101831/1968) and essentially replicates Python’s functionality. However, this doesn’t seem to be what you want since it won’t work as you expect when invoked by Knitr.

Comment: Thanks, if(interactive()) does what I want when invoked by Knitr, but not when invoked by another script in interactive mode. Maybe the last part of my question wasn't clear.

Comment: @Paul4forest No, it was clear. But like I said, there’s no ready solution for that.

Comment: Since I asked this question, I have [learned to put my code in R packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/). The need to source files has mostly disappeared. I build and load my package instead.

Comment: @PaulRougieux Funny, since answering this question [I’ve written a package, ‹modules›](https://github.com/klmr/modules), which serves to replace the cumbersome old-style R packages in favour of a more Pythonesque architecture. Of course I’m biased but I find modules vastly superior to packages in many aspects. Among other things, ‹modules› provides a direct equivalent to Python’s entry point, via the [‹sys› module](https://github.com/klmr/sys/).

Answer (score 1):

Another way I have found that will work as you described without the need to use  and change options is:

```
if (sys.nframe() == 0) {
    # ... do main stuff
}
```

`sys.nframe()` is equal to `0` when run from the interactive terminal or using `Rscript.exe`, in which case the main code will run. Otherwise when the code is `source`d, `sys.nframe()` is equal to `4` (in my case, not sure how it works exactly) which will prevent the main code from running.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74747919)